# Subversion 1.5+ on CentOS 5 - libldap issues

Tags: centos, svn, yum

I have a ClearOS box which has CentOS 5.4 under the hood.  I'd like to have a Subversion server on this too, and the CentOS repositories have SVN 1.4 available.  However, for authentication reasons I need to have 1.5 or greater.  Adding RPMForge to the Yum repositories, which seems to be the general rule, results in the following message:

```
[root@h ~]# yum --enablerepo=rpmforge install subversion
Loading "kmod" plugin
Loading "protect-packages" plugin
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package subversion.i386 0:1.6.6-0.1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: liblber-2.3.so.0 for package: subversion
--> Processing Dependency: libldap-2.3.so.0 for package: subversion
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Missing Dependency: liblber-2.3.so.0 is needed by package subversion
Error: Missing Dependency: libldap-2.3.so.0 is needed by package subversion
```

But I have libldap-2.4.so.0 available on the system, so I'd prefer not to downgrade it ;-)  I'd rather not do a custom build of Subversion, but I'm open to any suggestions as to how I can get it installed - forcing the RPM on its own maybe? What would be the best course of action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not yum, but...

Follow the links from the Subversion homepage for getting binaries.  They don't explicitly mention CentOS there, but RH is there.

Since you're on ES 5.x, Summersoft will have individual rpms up to pretty much the latest.  Pick your favorite version, and all the related prereqs should be there in the same directory.

Or, sign up free and download from CollabNet.  I believe you only pay if you want support.